# Explaining the parts of Simple PID python

Tags: python-3.x

I am very new to python and programming in general so I am hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction in my search for a solution;

In controlling a linear actuator, I need to be sure the speed is constant over varying loads.

- The motor controller receives byte values of 0(stopped)-127(full speed) over serial to control speed
- The position is a voltage from 0-5v with 5v being fully retracted and 0v being fully extended.

I have looked up simple - PID but Im not sure I understand how I would apply it in this case.
Essentially I would specify every 0.x seconds, check the position relative to the previous position, calculate the speed, and then update the speed value being sent over the serial port so I reach my speed setpoint.

If someone could detail what should go where, specifically what the tunings are for?

https://pypi.org/project/simple-pid/

Thanks!